# What models of Core i7 are available in the MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro

The <strike>current</strike>previous 17" MacBook Pro has three CPU options:

- 2.53GHz Intel Core i5 [Subtract $360.00]
- 2.66GHz Intel Core i7 [Subtract $180.00]
- 2.8GHz Intel Core i7

Does anyone know what the exact CPU model names are, and which of them have 4 cores?
I can't find additional details anywhere.

The speeds are higher than Dell's options, leading me to believe that they're all 2-core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specs are available at [this page](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/stats/macbook-pro-core-i5-2.53-aluminum-17-mid-2010-unibody-specs.html).

The 2.53 i5 is the [I5-540M](http://ark.intel.com/Product.aspx?id=43544) (2
   physical / 4 virtual cores, and Turbo
   Boost overclocking).

The 2.66 i7 is
   the [I7-620M](http://ark.intel.com/Product.aspx?id=43560) (2 physical / 4
   virtual, and Turbo Boost).
The 2.80 i7
   is the [I7-640M](http://ark.intel.com/Product.aspx?id=49666) (2 physical / 4
   virtual, Turbo Boost).

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the new (as of February 24<sup>th</sup>) 17" MacBook Pro offers a choice between the following two:

- [Core i7-2720QM](http://ark.intel.com/Product.aspx?id=50067) (2.2 GHz)
- [Core i7-2820QM](http://ark.intel.com/Product.aspx?id=52227) (2.3 GHz)

(Gleaned from comparison's between Apple's marketing and Wikipedia)

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**

New MacBook Pros were announced today, Feb 24.

Now, the 17" has the following options:

2.2 Quad Core i7

2.3 Quad Core i7

I will update with more info as soon as the Apple Online Store reopens and/or EveryMac updates.

Comment: The online store just reopened.  However, they don't say anything more than you did.